# Why can't I union 2 rows with JSON_ARRAY() in T-SQL?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

In SQL Server 2022 and Azure SQL, the function [`JSON_ARRAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-array-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) has been added.

This works:

```sql
select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) as array_col
```

This doesn't:

```sql
select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) as array_col
union all
select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) as array_col
```

The union gives me `[S0002][206] Line 1: Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is incompatible with void type`

So why would the union not work?

Comment: Although the docs say it is available on Azure SQL, I couldn't get it to work there. I'm testing this with the SQL Server 2022 Docker image.

Comment: what if you cast/convert one json_array() to nvarchar(max)?

Comment: @lptr Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I get the same error. Tried casting both of them as well.

Comment: Json_query() the array?

Comment: No ability to try this but perhaps a rowgoal could force the optimizer to treat the union correctly - eg union the result of `select top(100000)...` etc?

Answer (score 2):

Seems a bug to me, something happening with `union` (with or without `all`) and also with `intersect`, `except`, etc. before the JSON transformation converts the array to a simple string. But a join between two subqueries works:

```
select * FROM 
(select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) as array_col ) AS x
INNER JOIN 
(select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) as array_col) AS y
ON x.id = y.id;
```

I'd suggest filing a bug [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) (at least at the moment).

In the meantime, you can coerce slightly different behavior using explicit collation against the expressions:

```
select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) 
  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as array_col 
UNION ALL
select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) 
  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as array_col;
```

> [image]

For integers it probably doesn't matter what collation you use (only that you use the same one for all aligned expressions in the union!) but, for strings, you might instead use:

```
select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) 
  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT as array_col 
UNION ALL
select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) 
  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT as array_col;
```

An uglier workaround could be to forcefully materialize the output of both queries, and union *those*:

```
select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) as array_col into #x;
select 1 as id, JSON_ARRAY(1 , 2 , 3) as array_col into #y;
select * from #x union all select * from #y;
```

> [image]